# C Struct Initialization

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node Node;

int main() {
    Node a;
    a.data = 1;
    if (!a.next) {
        printf("hello world");
    }
}
```

I'm writing a little linked list program to start learning c, and I'm confused as to why a.next is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, whenever you allocate some memory in C (either explicitly or implicitly), the memory is initialized with whatever was there when the stack frame for your main function was created (ie. garbage).  This is true of your `int` value as well (remove the `a.data = 1` and print the value of `a.data`).  C doesn't zero the memory it allocates for you (which makes C more efficient).  As Anandha suggested, just set the pointer to `NULL` to avoid this problem.

Comment: is there a way to set a default value or I have to set it to null every time I make a Node

Comment: In addition, global variable is always zero without initialization

Comment: @ljd03 
struct node {
    int data = 0;
    struct node* next = 0;
};

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the pointer with NULL, the declared pointer may contain garbage value pointing to anywhere in the memory.

So `a.next=NULL`